# How to get spaces instead of tabs in eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, tabs, spaces

After doing a little research, I found out that eclipse hides its settings in multiple levels. So, I think, I got all the levels covered here.

Here I have set eclipse to insert spaces instead of tabs. And eclipse even acknowledges there that I have indeed set it up to insert 4 spaces instead of a tab (See the text under **Tabulators**: it says, *"The current indentation size is 4, using spaces"*).
[image: Tab Settings for C/C++]

Then for the general text editor, I have also set it up to insert spaces instead of the tabs.
[image: General Tab Settings]

#### And eclipse couldn't have gotten things more wrong even if it had tried!

1. Unfortunately, despite all those settings, when I press tab, eclipse inserts 2 spaces. Then, I press tab again, and it inserts 2 spaces. Why 2 spaces? Are there still more hidden settings somewhere?
2. Anyways, this broken system works a bit, until I have one level more of indentation, for example, for a for-loop or an if-block. If I press, tab again, instead of adding 2 more spaces, it converts the 6 spaces into a tab.
3. And a tab which is not even 4 spaces wide, but instead a tab which looks like a 6- or 8-spaces wide tab.
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> also adds tabs, not spaces.

The formatter is also setup as [@Neuron suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66116372/4298200).
[image: Formatter]

So, where else is eclipse hiding more settings?
[image: 2nd level indentation is automatically TAB]

Comment: In my honest opinion, maybe I am wrong, but I think, the c++ and c tags to the questions are valid, because of the language-specific settings (first image).

Comment: This really seems to be a C/C++ related issue. The tags where valid and should not have been removed

Comment: excuse my really stupid question, but did you also set the newly created profile as the "Active Profile" in the Formatter settings?

Comment: @Neuron, thank you for the feedback. Let me check that today and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by going to..

Window ⟶ Preferences ⟶ C/C++ ⟶ Code Style ⟶ Formatter

There you need to edit the currently set profile. Click "Edit..." (top right-ish). Now go to Indentation (already open) ⟶ General Settings ⟶ Tab Policy and change this from "Tabs only" to "Spaces only".

If you still have the default profile, give your profile a new name.

Why is this so weird and convoluted? I don't know.

Comment: @DuckDodgers 3 years later.. some problems take time to solve :D

Comment: I don't know what changed but this is not working.